# hibernate mapping issue - One to one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am not able to map `OrderApprovalLevels` and `QuoteApprovalLevels` one to one with `UserCustomer`. I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: oqtPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74) [hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288) [spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: orderApprovalLevel in poqt01.oqt_user_ic01
```

Source Code

```
/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: vartiwari
 * Date: 2/1/16
 * Time: 5:22 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")
@Entity
@Table(name = "oqt_user_ic01")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ftId")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.customer", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ic01s"))
})
public class UserCustomer implements Serializable{

    //'pk' refers to the composite key for oqt_user_ic01 with columns ftID for User and ic01 for Customer
    private UserCustomerId pk;
    private boolean ic01FromMSS;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name = "orderApprovalLevelId")
    private OrderApprovalLevels orderApprovalLevel;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name = "quoteApprovalLevelId")
    private QuoteApprovalLevels quoteApprovalLevel;

    @EmbeddedId
    public UserCustomerId getPk() {
        if(pk == null){
            pk = new UserCustomerId();
        }
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(UserCustomerId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public User getUser() {
        return getPk().getUser();
    }

    public void setUser(User user){
        getPk().setUser(user);
    }

    @Transient
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return getPk().getCustomer();
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer){
        getPk().setCustomer(customer);
    }

    @Column(name = "ic01FromMSS",nullable = false)
    public boolean isIc01FromMSS() {
        return ic01FromMSS;
    }

    public void setIc01FromMSS(boolean ic01FromMSS) {
        this.ic01FromMSS = ic01FromMSS;
    }


    public OrderApprovalLevels getOrderApprovalLevel() {
        return orderApprovalLevel;
    }

    public void setOrderApprovalLevel(OrderApprovalLevels orderApprovalLevel) {
        this.orderApprovalLevel = orderApprovalLevel;
    }

    public QuoteApprovalLevels getQuoteApprovalLevel() {
        return quoteApprovalLevel;
    }

    public void setQuoteApprovalLevel(QuoteApprovalLevels quoteApprovalLevel) {
        this.quoteApprovalLevel = quoteApprovalLevel;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="oqt_customer_quote_approval_levels")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings({"PMD.UnusedPrivateField", "PMD.SingularField"})
public class QuoteApprovalLevels implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;
    private Long approvalLevel;
    private String approvalLabel;
}
```

Comment: yes.. we have column orderApprovalLevelId  in oqt_user_ic01 which is mapped as foreign key to table oqt_customer_approval level.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace I am not sure if it is the cause of the error, but you are using mapping annotations on fields (field access) as well as on getters (property access) in which case the behavior is not defined. So you have to correct that first and if it still not working at least you have excluded one possible cause. For defining mixed access mode look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728671/column-annotation-does-not-work/38730149#38730149).

Comment: And one more thing, remove the `@Column` annotations from the `@OneToOne` annotation, instead use as user Shailendra pointed out `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: could you tell what should the modification be? I am not very clear with the solution you provided. Join column does not work.

Comment: Have you read the answer? You have to set `@Access` annotation on the entity if you want to use mixed mode.

Comment: Thanks.. We tried setting annotations on all the getters and it worked.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use @JoinColumn for [One-to-One](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) relation

```
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderApprovalLevelId")
    private OrderApprovalLevels orderApprovalLevel;
```